# an example of localstorage combobox for extjs

Tags: extjs

I am new to the extjs and try to make following codes work:

I tried as you suggested, still no luck:

```
var bookmarks=[];
bookmarks[0] ={id:'111111111', target:'target', title:'title', category:'category', created:'created'};
bookmarks[1] ={id:'22222222222', target:'target', title:'title22222222', category:'category', created:'created'};
localStorage['myapp-bookmarks']=JSON.stringify(bookmarks);

Ext.define("BookMark", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model', 
    idProperty: "id",
    fields: ['id','target','title','category','created'] 
});

var bookmarkStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "BookMark",
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'bookmarks',
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'myapp-bookmarks'
    }
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the above store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: bookmarkStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'title',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

But it won't populate the list for me. Any idea?

Comment: You should give displayField and valueField actual field name, in your case id,target,title,category,created. You gave name and type respectively which are not fields.You can remove name and type from field:[] in Model and create field as fields:['id','target','title','category','created'] in Model

Comment: Looks like i have to manually load it: http://jsfiddle.net/netnet/pnc7L/7/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, not sure why you think you would have to manually load it (using the code you wrote in your jsfiddle link above). See here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage I tried the above and it works for me (Ext JS 4.2.1)